# Typical normalization security issue in web applications

Tags: sql, security, web-applications, normalization

i am currently having a problem, i guess a lot of people have run into before and i would like to know how you handled it.

So, imagine you have 10.000 Users on your App. ( each one has an own user/pw login to administrate his stuff ).
Imagine further, that you have a growing normalized SQL-tablestructure in the backend, with tables like: Users, Orders, OrderPositions, Invoices, etc.

So, to show/edit/delete stuff of a table which isn't the usertable itself, u'll probably have links like these, to let ypur users interact with the application.

```
~/Orders/EditOrder?id=12    
~/Orders/ShowOrderPosition?orderId=12&posId=443
```

**Ok, and now the problem:**

How, do i prevent in a "none-complex"-way, that user A has access ( show/edit/delete ) the data of user B.

Example:

User B calls:

```
~/Orders/ShowOrderPosition?orderId=12&posId=443
```

which is an order of user A, so user B should have no access to it.

So, in my code i would need to have a UserIdentity-check before or within **every single SQL-statement**, like:

```
select * from OrderPosition op, Order o, User u 
   where op.Id = :orderId 
     and op.Fk_OrderId = :orderpositionId
     and o.Id = :orderId
     and o.Fk_User = :userId
```

Only this way i can make sure, that the data belongs to the requesting user.

To reach the usertable will of course get far more complex, the deeper the usertable-connection is "buried" in the normalization ( imagine tables like payments or invoices, connected to the order-table...  )

**Question:**

What is your approach to deal with this, concidering: **Low complexity, DRY and performance**

( Hope u understand what i mean ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit like a multi-tenant application - I have gone down this route and denormalized an ID onto all those tables that require this kind of check (a tenant ID, in your case, sounds like the user id).

I then created an interface that contains this field only and applied it to all those classes in my model layer that required this access.

In my base data access (repository) class, where all the select/update/delete calls go through, I then check to see if the class if of the type of that interface, and I then check that the current access matches that ID.

---

Of course, this depends on how your code is structured, and how simple/complex making this global kind of change will be...

Comment: Exactly what we did.
"onto all those tables" - for us meant typical Order table but not OrderDetail table, because we never accessed the OrderDetail without joining in the Order table before.

Comment: I agree.  Except for the "denormalised an ID" **label** which leads to confusion: if it is required, it is not a "denormalisation".  In fact, the PK should have the user_id as the last column, which it would have had, if the tables had been Normalised in the first place, without `Id` iot columns.  The tables were Unnormalised, and you just corrected them.  Denormalised implies that you had a correctly Normalised db, and you reversed the process.  People need to get used to compound keys.

Answer (score 0):

Never expose ids.

And if you have to: encrypt them.

Comment: Why not?  Surely encryption is just a little bit of 'security by obscurity'

Comment: Yes, i am with paddy here... No "real" security after all

Comment: Well, every little bit counts when security is concerned. Not exposing IDs can add some protection against future security holes. For example, if you assume that webapp is properly secured then not knowing IDs will make it harder for someone to exploit a newly discovered security hole of the type OP mentions (of course if someone roots the system or the DB it will have no effect). In another words - if someone, by mistake, exposes unsecured URL which bypass regular webapp security layer then not knowing IDs can make all the difference between successful exploit and triggering some honeypot.

Answer (score 0):

**Performance**

- for ultimate performance you will have to denormalize to the point that reading the row and comparing with some application level variable would give you an answer on what kind of rights the user has (this is fairly fast and if your DAO/BAO level is well organized plugging it in will keep it relatively DRY and at relatively low complexity.) NOTE: complexity is also a function of your security model, once you start to implement inheritable, positive and negative, role-based access rules then it can not be really simple.

**DRY**

- another route to take (which is very seldomly taken these days) is to use your database roles to manage security; this might get complicated but will offer unparalleled security (as it will be ensured at the DB level and not application level. Complexity should go down, at the application code level, if you manage to encapsulate all of your access paths into VIEWS, which might require quite a bit of re-tailoring at the database level. However(!), it might be possible to implement security model with very little changes to the application code - by renaming existing tables and replacing them with secured views)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your internal ID column, encrypted or not, it'll come back to bite you one day.

Create a random, unique, string (GUID, whatever), which contains the link between the user and the data he's requesting. So, instead of having, for user 34567:

```
<a href="~/Orders/EditOrder?id=12">Edit order</a>
```

Create a record {"5dsfwe8frf823jrf",34567,12} in a temporary table and show:

```
<a href="~/Orders/EditOrder?txn=5dsfwe8frf823jrf">Edit order</a>
```

When the users clicks the link, fetch `34567,12` from your temporary table.

The string `5dsfwe8frf823jrf` is impossible to guess = no security risk.